# Moving SVN to other server error

Tags: svn

I must move my SVN to a new server, so I wanted to create its copy.

```
svnadmin create c:\backuprepo
echo exit 0 > c:\backuprepo\hooks\pre-revprop-change.bat
svnsync init file:///c:/backuprepo https://url/of/your/repository
svnsync sync file:///c:/backuprepo
```

and the copy was been done (I hope I've done it correctly). Then, I want to test it, so I want to checkout:

```
server_ip:8080/backuprepo
```

and I get the error:

[image: imgerror]

Maybe the port number is wrong ? Any ideas how to fix it ?

### EDIT 1

according to the [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8803050/106616)'s answer, I get that error:
[image]

### EDIT 2

SOLVED:

I had to additionally install the VisualSVN Server. Inside it, I've created the user account for the repository, then I run again all the scripts (the top of this topic). Aha, I had also set tup the 443 port number during the VisualSVN installation

Comment: Is the URL actually missing `https://`?

Comment: Álvaro G. Vicario > then I get the time out error - it can't connect

Comment: Copy: assuming you're sticking to the same OS and endianness (and maybe if you're not, not sure) you can just shut down the main server and copy the repository files as-is.

Comment: What exactly have you installed and configured in the new server? Apart from copying the data, you need to install Subversion as well.

Comment: It's the VPS server running on the Windows 2008 Server R2. I've installed on it only the TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is similar to [this thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-dev/201112.mbox/%3CCAHU89aXwR__p6MvuRYwORvqBBeem_Vjc1d6f1x9o06BF=R_TWg@mail.gmail.com%3E):

```
'D:\Development\SVN\Releases\TortoiseSVN-1.7.3\ext\subversion\subversion\libsvn_client\checkout.c'
 line 94: assertion failed (svn_uri_is_canonical(url, pool))
```

> then my guess is that the lack of a URI scheme and "`://`" prefix caused the assertion.

In other words, a `https://server_ip:8080/backuprepo` address should work better.

Comment: Additionally, I suspect that Apache is not configured to serve the new repo under that URL (copy went fine since it was using `file://` protocol). I have the impression that the OP is moving the repo in an unnecessarily complex way.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: yes, I agree.