# git-svn clone dying with signal 6

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

So I have been cloning a bunch of projects in my repository in order to migrate over to Git. I have been able to successfully clone all of them except for one. It happens to be the largest project, but I am not sure if this is relevant. During the clone, I am getting a 'git-svn died of signal 6' error. Specifically

```
"Assertion failed: (svn_uri_is_canonical(child_uri, NULL)), function uri_skip_ancestor, file subversion/libsvn_subr/dirent_uri.c"
error: git-svn died of signal 6.
```

It is failing the Assertion that checks if a URI is canonical. Unfortunately it takes about 4 hours to reach the point where it fails, so making changes and re-cloning is extremely impractical. I read all about URI's needing to be canonical because of the way that SVN handles URI's internally. I read all about changing the .git/config file by removing double slashes or trailing slashes... which I don't have any of. I just cannot figure out why only this project is failing. Does anyone have any ideas as to what specific about a project could be causing this when all of my 16 other projects cloned with no problem? Also, the project is in a very standard trunk-branches-tags format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singal 6 is defined to be `SIGABRT` — this is a special signal which is sent to a process when it calls `abort(3)`. In most cases the process does not handle this signal, and the standard disposition of this signal is to kill the process, which is what happens in your case.  Supposedly the assertion checking code calls `abort(3)` in the end.

As to the possible solutions, [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q="Assertion+failed"+"svn_uri_is_canonical") yields at least [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8803050/720999) as well as a number of other pointers — try to work through them.